# How to add icon in the headerLinks in Docusaurus project

Tags: docusaurus

To add headerLinks, code is

```
 headerLinks: [
    { doc: "introduction", label: "Docs" },
    { doc: "faq", label: "FAQ" },
    {
      href: "https://github.com",
      label: "Github",
    },

    {
      href: "https://example.com",
      label: "Hire Us",
    },
```

I want to add an icon before "Hire Us" content. What should I write?

Answer (score 8):

You can check the css from the github repo:

[https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/css/custom.css[enter](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/css/custom.css%5Benter) link description here][1](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/css/custom.css)

```css
.header-github-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.header-github-link:before {
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
    no-repeat;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] .header-github-link:before {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill='white' d='M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
    no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of `Navbar with custom HTML` and add the ccs straight into the value.

Basic example for icon and link to an Azure DevOps repo:

```js
// docusaurus.config.js

module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      items: [
          {
            type: 'html',
            position: 'right',
            value: '<a href="https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization}/{your-project}/_git/{your-docusaurus-repo}" target="_blank" style="content: \'\'; width: 24px; height: 24px; background-image: url(\'https://cdn.vsassets.io/ext/ms.vss-code-web/common-content/Nav-Code.0tJczm.png\'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: 24px 24px; display: flex">'
          },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Ref: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#navbar-with-custom-html

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it maintaining the same style as the theme toggle button using [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/):

**1. Installation:**

First, navigate to the root of your Docusaurus project. Then, install FontAwesome using any package manager, for example npm:

```bash
npm install --save font-awesome
```

**2. Import FontAwesome:**

At the top of your `/src/css/custom.css` file, add the following import:

```css
@import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

**3. Style the GitHub Icon:**

Add the following CSS to your `src/css/custom.css`:

```css
.navbar__icon {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.navbar__github {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  transition: background var(--ifm-transition-fast);
}

html[data-theme='light'] .navbar__github {
  color: #000;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] .navbar__github {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__github:hover {
  background: var(--ifm-color-emphasis-200);
}
```

**4. Update the Docusaurus Config:**

Finally, integrate it into your navbar by updating the `docusaurus.config.js`:

```js
navbar: {
  // ... Other navbar configurations ...
  items: [
    // ... Other navbar items ...
    {
      href: 'https://github.com/{username}/{repo}',
      'aria-label': 'GitHub',
      className: 'navbar__icon navbar__github',
      position: 'right',
      html: '<i class="fa fa-github"></i>',
    },
  ],
},
```

**Bonus. Add other icons:**

Add the same for `navbar__twitter` and `fa fa-twitter` or any other .

---

Let me know if this works also for you.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @regexAgainstTheMachine answer, to automatically fill (color) the icon according to your theme

```css
.navbar__github:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  mask: url(/img/github.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  mask-size: cover;
  background-color: var(--ifm-navbar-link-color);
}

.navbar__github:hover:before {
  background-color: var(--ifm-navbar-link-hover-color);
}
```

This can be used generically for additional icons

```css
.navbar__icon:before {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-color: var(--ifm-navbar-link-color);
}

.navbar__icon:hover:before {
  background-color: var(--ifm-navbar-link-hover-color);
}

.navbar__github:before {
  mask: url(/img/github.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  mask-size: cover;
}

.navbar__twitter:before {
  mask: url(/img/twitter.svg) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  mask-size: cover;
}
```

docusaurus.config.js

```js
        items: [
          {
            'aria-label': 'Twitter',
            to: twitter,
            position: 'right',
            className: 'navbar__icon navbar__twitter',
          },
          {
            'aria-label': 'GitHub repo',
            to: repo,
            position: 'right',
            className: 'navbar__icon navbar__github',
          },
        ],
```